# Create a runnable file from .java files and png images

Tags: java

I have 2 individual .java files, and in those files, I have taken in some buffered images, which are 3 .png files. I want to turn this grouping, the 2 java files and the 3 png images into a single file that can be opened and executed without a compiler. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build a `jar` file for this. So you will be able to run your application by double clicking on your `.jar` file. If you are using `netbeans` to develop you can simply do it by right click on your application and by selecting `clean and build`.
I hope [this link](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/createjar.html) will help you.